# How to store Master table data

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am involved in project where a table having master data which need to be updated yearly wise.

For example, course list table for the year 2018

**table_course**

```
id  name
1   Maths
2   Science
```

course list table for the year 2019

```
id  name
1   Social
2   Language
```

what we have designed

```
id  name     year
1   Maths    2018
2   Science  2018
3   Social   2018
4   Language 2018
```

How to design this table in better way.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to achieve. But from your question details i can assume that you need a table that contains all different courses.

**courses**

```
+-----------+---------+
| COURSE_ID |  NAME   |
+-----------+---------+
|         1 | Math    |
|         2 | Science |
+-----------+---------+
```

And a history log table

**courses_years**

```
+-----------+------+
| COURSE_ID | YEAR |
+-----------+------+
|         1 | 2018 |
|         1 | 2019 |
|         2 | 2019 |
+-----------+------+
```

The first table is the main table with all atomic entities. You have a primary key based on auto increment number (which is questionable, but this is for another question) and unique constraint on the name.

The second table is just a log table of your courses history. You have a foreign key pointing at **course_id** and a primary key based on two columns.